# How improve the performance of the iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge dataset which I need calculate the amount of repetitive items for each row.
For instance: In a specific row I have the customer X. I need create a new column which will present how many times the customer X is registred in the dataset.
I did a code about that, but the performance is very bad. I´ll spend about 3 days until the dataset will be completed.
Could someone help to improve the performance of this calculation? Below is an example of my idea:

```
#importing resources
import sys
import pandas as pd
from __future__ import print_function
```

```
#creating a dataset as example:
df1= pd.DataFrame({'Customer':["Wilfred","Abner","Rishcash","Debie"],'Dealer':["Alpha","Beta","Gama","Delta"],'Vehicle_model':["Jeep","Volks","Chrysler","Volvo"],'CITY':["Osasco","Denver","Rome","Tokyo"]})
```

```
#creating new columns
df1['Qtd leads']=1
df1['Qtd dealers']=1
df1['Leads City']=1
df1['Leads State']=1
df1['Leads V_Model']=1
```

```
#function to estimate repetitive values
def cont(quem):
    a=df1['Customer'].value_counts()[quem]
    return a
```

```
#iterate in the dataset
i=0
for i in df1.index:
    df1['Qtd leads'][i]=df1['Customer'].value_counts()[df1['Customer'][i]]
    df1['Qtd dealers'][i]=df1['Dealer'].value_counts()[df1['Dealer'][i]]
    df1['Leads V_Model'][i]=df1['Vehicle_model'].value_counts()[df1['Vehicle_model'][i]]
    df1['Leads City'][i]=df1['CITY'].value_counts()[df1['CITY'][i]]
    print(i, end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Do you really want to have in each row the info how often each customer, dealer and vehicle  is seen in total or do you want to just know these numbers ones?

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby and merge.

Example for CITY:

```
dfcity = df1.groupby(by='CITY').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0 : 'Leads City'})
df1 = pd.merge(df1,dfcity,on='CITY')
```

`df1.groupby(by='CITY')` groups your dataframe by 'CITY'. This gives you a groupby object with a lot of nice functions for looking at these grouped data- e.g. `size()`.

`.size()` gives you then a dataframe with the city as index and how often it is seen as column 0.

`reset_index()` then reverts the index into a column, so you have two columns: CITY and 0.

Next you rename the 0 column (`.rename(columns={0 : 'Leads City'})`)

Finally you merge your original dataframe with the new one on the column 'CITY'

`df1 = pd.merge(df1,dfcity,on='CITY')`

You can repeat that for each column you want to count.

Comment: Awesome!...quick and clean! Thank you!